# How to list groups of an attribute set using REST API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, product-attribute, rest-api

I am trying to use the Magento 2 rest API to list the groups of an attribute set:

`GET /V1/products/attribute-sets/groups/list`

But the request fails with the following error:

```
{
  "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
  "parameters": {
    "fieldName": "attribute_set_id"
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find how to pass the required field and there is no documentation on how that should be passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your URL request. But, if you want to call `GET /V1/products/attribute-sets/groups/list`, need an Admin token and add `searchCriteria`. For example:

```
<?php

$userData = ["username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123"];
$ch = curl_init("http://mage220.loc/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$searchCondition = "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_set_id&" ;
$searchCondition = $searchCondition .  "searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&" ;
$searchCondition = $searchCondition ."searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq";

$ch = curl_init("http://mage220.loc/rest/V1/products/attribute-sets/groups/list/?" . $searchCondition);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); // Request method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_group_id] => 1
                    [attribute_group_name] => General
                    [attribute_set_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [search_criteria] => Array
        (
            [filter_groups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [filters] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => attribute_set_id
                                            [value] => 1
                                            [condition_type] => eq
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [total_count] => 1
)
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/performing-searches.html

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't clear in my question, but other endpoints wore working correctly. It just wasn't clear to me how to use searchCriteria (I was missing the condition_type)

Answer (score 1):

try this buddy,

```
/V1/products/attribute-sets/groups/list?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_set_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]={your attribute-set Id}
```

It'll work for sure