# API: Accessing All attributes associated to a Attribute-Group

Tags: magento2, attributes, rest-api, attribute-set

So I'm in need to check to see if an attribute group contains a specific attribute_id. However using the API, there doesn't appear to be a specific endpoint which lists all attributes associated to a group, only to an attribute set.

What I was hoping to achieve was to use the endpoint:

```
/rest/default/V1/products/attribute-sets/{attributeSetId}/attributes
```

and use `searchCriteria[filterGroups]` to search for a group_id field which doesn't appear to exist.

Does anyone know if this is even possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Admin Token?
Is your query using snake case and keys for each filter? `searchCriteria[filter_groups][0]`

This might help you too:
[How to list groups of an attribute set using REST API in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205196/how-to-list-groups-of-an-attribute-set-using-rest-api-in-magento-2)